# Cannot access folder path header file in solution

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I imported one project to another project by following this link [tutorial](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules#Create_an_Xcode_project_for_the_static_library)

successfully build that two project. But when I added
`#import <SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h>`  this to my main `ViewController.m` file error be occur.
Error : **"SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h" file is not found.**

[image]

Why is that error occurred ??
Is there any error ?
Please help me guys!

Comment: Try just SampleSubproject.h instead of SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h

Comment: I tried. but still it is not showing that file path.
When I added libsample.a file into main project in that name color changed to red.So is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

You have `Headers search path` settings at project configuration. Let's say there're directories `A` and `B`. With "SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h" Xcode looks for `SampleSubproject.h` at `A/SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h` and `B/SampleSubproject/SampleSubproject.h`. If there's a checked `recursive` flag for any directories, the search is performed at this directories and their subdirectories.

Now you'll need to check what is the headers search path for the target you are building keeping in mind that you might have several targets and the file with the import might not be included into all the targets.

---

As you also have a red library, you'll want to check the `Libraries search path` as well, it works in the same way.